# Developing for the RenRen social network

Tags: python, api, rest

I have a Django-based API to interact with social networks, and I would like to integrate with RenRen.

My main problem is not a programming one, but how to create an application for RenRen. I try to navigate the site http://app.renren.com/ using Google Translate to help, but I can't create an app.

I am always redirected to the page to input my information. I am wondering wether I need to input all my personal information and have it verified before I can create an app. On top of that, I am not of Chinese nationality, so I don't have an identity document that would be acceptable.

Can anybody with experience developing for RenRen shed some light on how to create an app?

Comment: Maybe you'd have more luck asking this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Yes, I suppose you are right. It's not really a programming question. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

the best link for Renren dev is :http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/%E7%A7%BB%E5%8A%A8%E5%AE%A2%E6%88%B7%E7%AB%AF%E6%8E%A5%E5%85%A5

Yes, Renren requires developer a Renren registered account. However, ID document is not required for the registration, only username, email, password are required. So there should be no problem for you to create a Renren app.

Just same as other API service, Oauth 2.0 is employed for authorization.  The Renren dev document is not as good as those of Google or Facebook, but it works.